# Rails 3 form_tag opens javascript in a new page instead of loading it in the current page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

View:

```
form_tag(url_for(:controller => :matchers,
                :action => :show_matched_alarms_list),
        :remote => true,
        :method =>:get,             
        :class => "matcher_ajax_form") do |f|
```

Controller:

```
layout 'application',:except=>[:show_matched_alarms_list]
def show_matched_alarms_list
  @matcher= ...
  render :update do |page|
    page.replace('matched_alarms_list',
                 :partial => 'matchers/matched_alarms_list',
                 :locals=>{:matcher=>@matcher})
  end
end
```

This is opening the Returned Javascript in a new page instead of loading it in the opened page. Does anyone know how to fix this?

I am using prototype. The form looks like this:

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" 
      action="/matchers/show_matched_alarms_list" 
      class="matcher_ajax_form" 
      data-remote="true" 
      method="get">
```

Comment: Are you using jQuery or Prototype? What does the generated `<form>` tag look like? JavaScript errors in the tag can cause the `remote` behavior to malfunction.

Comment: I updated my question to answer the previous question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed this.

The problem was that I submiting the form using the **form.submit()** method, which apparently doesn not work fine when using a remote form. I replaced it for the **form.request()** method and it worked as expected.